# Convert an image into a 2D array (or equivalent) in Apple Swift

Tags: swift, image, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering how I can turn a UIImage into something usable and modifiable. **Java** code to handle what I need would look something like this:

```
BufferedImage img= ImageIO.read(file);
Raster raster=img.getData();
int w=raster.getWidth(),h=raster.getHeight();
int pixels[][]=new int[w][h];
for (int x=0;x<w;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
    {
        pixels[x][y]=raster.getSample(x,y,0);
    }
}
```

I need to modify the alpha values in an image by visiting each pixel in the image.

Comment: you may have more luck by first searching for how to do this in Objective-C (hint - it'll be nothing like the Java) and then converting the ObjC code to Swift.

Comment: I'm very surprised that Swift doesn't have an stl for working with images/pixels

Comment: Swift has very little by way of standard library.  The UIImage class is imported from Cocoa so you'll need to research Cocoa-based methods of manipulating the image.  You may even find a CoreImage filter that can apply whatever effect it is you need without having to edit the alpha values yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think this will either work or should be very close.

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics


var uiimage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "/PATH/TO/image.png")
var image = uiimage.CGImage


let width = CGImageGetWidth(image)
let height = CGImageGetHeight(image)
let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bytesPerRow = (4 * width);
let bitsPerComponent :UInt = 8
let pixels = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(malloc(width*height*4))


var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorspace,
  CGBitmapInfo());

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), image)


for x in 0..width {
  for y in 0..height {
    //Here is your raw pixels
    let offset = 4*((Int(width) * Int(y)) + Int(x))
    let alpha = pixels[offset]
    let red = pixels[offset+1]
    let green = pixels[offset+2]
    let blue = pixels[offset+3]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need conversion to 2D array, render image into byte array via CGContext and then split array to parts. CGContext uses 0...255 color range instead of 0...1. Byte array will be in rgba format.

Sample code with conversion to 0...1:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

func pixelData() -> [UInt8]? {
    let dataSize = size.width * size.height * 4
    var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(dataSize))
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,
                            width: Int(size.width),
                            height: Int(size.height),
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: 4 * Int(size.width),
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage,
          let context = context else { return nil }
    context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    
    return pixelData
}


func pixelMatrix() -> [[[Float]]]? {
    guard let pixels = pixelData() else {
        return nil
    }
    var data: [[[Float]]] = []
    
    let width = Int(size.width)
    let height = Int(size.height)
    
    for y in 0..<height {
        var row: [[Float]] = []
        for x in 0..<width {
            let offset = 4 * ((width * y) + x)
            
            let red = Float(pixels[offset]) / 255
            let green = Float(pixels[offset + 1]) / 255
            let blue = Float(pixels[offset + 2]) / 255
            let alpha = Float(pixels[offset + 3]) / 255
            let pixel = [red, green, blue, alpha]
            row.append(pixel)
        }
        data.append(row)
    }
    return data
}
```